# Как подключиться к БД MySQL через Node.js?

Tags: mysql, node.js, angular2

Я хочу подключиться к БД MySQL через Node.js в моем проекте на Angular Universal.

Код подключения:

```
var mysql = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
          host     : 'localhost',
          user     : 'root',
          password : 'root',
          database : 'dbname',
          port: '8889'
        });

connection.connect(function(err) {
          if (err) {
            console.log("Error connecting to DB: " + err);
            throw err;
          }
        });
```

Вначале я получаю такую ошибку:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined
        at Protocol._enqueue (/Applications/MAMP/htdocs/Angular2/myproject/node_modules/mysql/lib/protocol/Protocol.js:152:5)
...
```

Через несколько секунд выводится следующая ошибка:

```
Error connecting to DB: Error: Connection lost: The server closed the connection.
```

Посоветуйте, пожалуйста, как создать корректное подключение.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 0):

Ошибка:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined ...
```

возникает, если версия **Zone.js** не соответствует требуемой.

Я получал предупреждения:

```
angular2-universal@2.1.0-rc.1 requires a peer of zone.js@~0.6.21 but none was installed.
```

Команда для **установки Zone.js**:

```
npm install zone.js@0.6.21 --save-dev
```

Теперь данные из базы данных MySQL успешно возвращаются.